# How to get sha1sum to work on Mac OS X?

Tags: perl, osx-mavericks, sha1

I have an application that I'm porting and as part of the test suite, I run `sha1sum`.  I'd like to have test code that works on all my platforms and not vary across platforms.  Mac OS X, is the first platform without a `sha1sum` application.  I did find a `shasum` application though.  So I created a symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/local/bin; ln -s /usr/bin/shasum sha1sum
```

However, the test now fails with a Perl error:

```
bash-3.2$ sha1sum -c files.sha1sum
perl version 5.16.2 can't run /usr/local/bin/sha1sum.  Try the alternative(s):

(Error: no alternatives found)

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.

bash-3.2$ shasum -c files.sha1sum
smallData.txt: OK
```

The contents of /usr/bin/shasum are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

=for comment

The contents of this script should normally never run!  The perl wrapper
should pick the correct script in /usr/bin by appending the appropriate version.
You can try appending the appropriate perl version number.  See perlmacosx.pod
for more information about multiple version support in Mac OS X.

=cut

use strict;
use Config ();

my @alt = grep {m,^$0\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?$,} glob("$0*");
print STDERR <<"EOF-A";
perl version $Config::Config{version} can't run $0.  Try the alternative(s):

EOF-A
if(scalar(@alt) > 0) {
    for(@alt) {
    my($ver) = /(\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/;
    print STDERR "$_ (uses perl $ver)\n";
    }
} else {
    print STDERR "(Error: no alternatives found)\n";
}
die <<'EOF-B';

Run "man perl" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
EOF-B
```

How can I get a `sha1sum` executable in my search path that will work like `shasum` does?

Comment: This might be of use: https://raam.org/2008/howto-install-md5sum-sha1sum-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shasum` is just a wrapper for either `shasum5.12` or `shasum5.16` for `perl` v5.12 or `perl` v5.16.

Therefore, place the link in `/usr/bin` (instead of `/usr/local/bin`) and create links for the other two version specific ones too like this:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s shasum sha1sum
ln -s shasum5.12 sha1sum5.16
ln -s shasum5.16 sha1sum5.16
```

Now it works:

```
bash-3.2$ sha1sum -c files.sha1sum
smallData.txt: OK
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: perl version 5.18.2 can't run /usr/bin/sha1sum.  Try the alternative(s):

Comment: @sleepycal, did your comment get cut off? What alternatives were you referring to?